# When using the dataframe to CSV command, is there a way to upload it automatically to a git repo?

Tags: python, pandas, git, dataframe, csv

so I want to know if there is a way to when using the pandas.DataFrame.to_csv command that would let me save the CSV to a git repo. I saw another forum that said that if you use the git path as a parameter in the code snippet, that it would work, but I can't get it to work.

```
repo_path = "https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld/test.csv"
final_table_df.to_csv(repo_path,sep='\t', columns=['Names'], index = False)
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Just updated the original post

Comment: Note that Git itself does not store *files:* Git stores *commits* (which then store files, but the point here is that you don't just "upload a file", but rather, make a commit and then send the commit: each commit has a snapshot of *every* file, like a tarball or zip archive, but with much better storage usage).

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a file to a git repository using the to_csv method. You could save the CSV file to your local git directory and then push to your remote repository.

```
final_table_df.to_csv('local_git_folder/test.csv')
```

```
cd local_git_folder
git add test.csv
git commit -m 'my commit message'
git push
```